# Check if content is in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

How would I check if the page is being loaded in an iframe? Also, could I make a page change the main URL to its own from within an iframe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can iframe pages tell when they are iframed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509477/can-iframe-pages-tell-when-they-are-iframed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the parent's tag/nodeName :

```
theParent = $(this).parent();
//alert(theParent[0].nodeName);
```

Answer (score 3):

Both are possible and explained extensively in this post:

[Coding Horror - We Done Been...Framed!](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/06/we-done-been-framed.html)

Keep in mind that these are not perfect solutions since the parent page can prevent you from doing these things using various methods (also discussed in the post).